# Change Banner ClickTag Code to AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have been handed a number of Flash (AS3) banners to add ClickTag codes to them and as the documents have been setup as AS3 it does not allow code added to items!

I need help changing the following code to AS3 asap if anyone can help?

```
on (release) {
   getURL (_level0.clickTag, "_blank");
}
```

I cannot change the document back to AS2 as they have been created through InDesign and the filters don't work if I change them back!

Thanks,

Thomas.

Comment: please google your issue before asking such question. http://getclicktag.com/get-clicktag-code/

Comment: Referring people to google is seriously discouraged, @Aralicia. If the question is already on Stackoverflow, flag it as duplicate. If it isn't, leave it. The point of SO is to get a website with all the answers in the world, not to fill it with "Google it"!!!

Comment: I'm sorry, I've seen the same reply on a few questions. I thought it was accepted.

Comment: If everybody jumps off the bridge, do you as well?

Comment: @Aralicia If you type the information you found in an answer and explain it, it can be accepted. I don't see this question anywhere else on SO as far as I can see.

Comment: Hi @Aralicia thanks but I had already google'd it and the first site I saw was the one you had suggested but as the click tag code was different "getURL (_level0.clickTag, "_blank");" to the one suggested on the site "getURL(_root.clickTAG, '_blank');" and me not being a Flash person I don't know how to translate the beginning part "_level0". Thanks Joetjah.

Comment: _level0 and _root where more or less the same thing in AS2 (_root = the root of the swf / _level0 => the root of the first loaded swf). In AS3, _level0 doesn't exist anymore, and the new root is really different of the old one.

Comment: @Joetjah If everybody jumps off the bridge, I'll look if they survived before enything else. Since they did, I didn't see the issue. I wont do it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In AS3, the on(event) workflow has been replaced with the event system; and getURL() as been renamed navigateToURL() witch is more clear about what the function does.

```
// 'import' the necessary resources : If you don't do this, you'll have error while compiling.
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;

// theBanner is the name of your clickable MovieClip. If you add the code in the MovieClip, use 'this' instead
// this line indicate to call "onClick" if MOUSE_UP occurs on theBanner (ie : the user release the mouse hover the MovieClip
theBanner.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onClick);

// The onClick function, how open the new clickTag URL when called
function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
  // get the clickTag URL (root.loaderInfo.parameters.clickTag), and send it to navigateToURL.
  navigateToURL(new URLRequest(root.loaderInfo.parameters.clickTag), '_blank');
}
```